# Multiple obj elements loaded in same viewport

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to load multiple obj models into individual scenes. This is based on [webgl_multiple_elements.html](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html). I am loading one single obj file and wished to add it to each of the individual scenes. The obj is loading, but I cannot seem to find a way to get the model to show in the given scenes. If I run the geometries in the above example everything works as expected when adding the obj instead of the basic geometries nothing breaks, but the model cannot be seen.

```html
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }
    a {
        color: #08f;
    }
    #content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 3em 0 0 0;
    }
    #c {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .list-item {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }
    .list-item .scene {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .list-item .description {
        color: #888;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: large;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<div id="content">
    <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - multiple elements - webgl</div>
</div>

<script id="template" type="notjs">
    <div class="scene"></div>
    <div class="description">Scene $</div>
</script>
<script>
    var canvas;
    var scenes = [], renderer;

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    var objFlag = null;

    loadObject();

    function loadObject(){
        loader.load("./test_obj.json", 

        function( objectLoaded ) {
            objFlag = objectLoaded;
            init();
            animate();
        }, 
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' ,error);
        }
        );
    }

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById( "c" );
        var geometries = [
            new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ),
            new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 0.5, 12, 8 ),
            new THREE.DodecahedronBufferGeometry( 0.5 ),
            new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 0.5, 0.5, 1, 12 )
        ];
        var template = document.getElementById( "template" ).text;
        var content = document.getElementById( "content" );
        for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // make a list item
            var element = document.createElement( "div" );
            element.className = "list-item";
            element.innerHTML = template.replace( '$', i + 1 );
            // Look up the element that represents the area
            // we want to render the scene
            scene.userData.element = element.querySelector( ".scene" );
            content.appendChild( element );
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, 1, 1, 10 );
            camera.position.z = 2;
            scene.userData.camera = camera;
            // setup the controls
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( scene.userData.camera, scene.userData.element );
            controls.minDistance = 2;
            controls.maxDistance = 5;
            controls.enablePan = false;
            controls.enableZoom = false;
            scene.userData.controls = controls;
            // add one random mesh to each scene
            var geometry = geometries[ geometries.length * Math.random() | 0 ];
            var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
                color: new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random(), 1, 0.75 ),
                roughness: 0.5,
                metalness: 0
            } );
            // scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
            scene.add(objFlag);
            scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xaaaaaa, 0x444444 ) );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            scenes.push( scene );
        }
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, antialias: true } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    }
    function updateSize() {
        var width = canvas.clientWidth;
        var height = canvas.clientHeight;
        if ( canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height ) {
            renderer.setSize( width, height, false );
        }
    }
    function animate() {
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    }
    function render() {
        updateSize();
        // enables the canvas to scroll with the window for alignment
        canvas.style.transform = `translateY(${window.scrollY}px)`;
        // clips the canvas to the viewport
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
        renderer.setScissorTest( false );
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xe0e0e0 );
        renderer.setScissorTest( true );
        scenes.forEach( function ( scene ) {
            // so something moves
            scene.children[ 0 ].rotation.y = Date.now() * 0.001;
            // get the element that is a place holder for where we want to
            // draw the scene
            var element = scene.userData.element;
            // get its position relative to the page's viewport
            var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            // set the viewport
            var width = rect.right - rect.left;
            var height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            var left = rect.left;
            var bottom = renderer.domElement.clientHeight - rect.bottom;
            renderer.setViewport( left, bottom, width, height );
            renderer.setScissor( left, bottom, width, height );
            var camera = scene.userData.camera;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        } );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the necessary code _in the question itself_, as outlined in the [Help center's Asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is important so if your repo gets deleted, others in the future can still understand the question that was asked.

Comment: @Marquizzo I have updated the question to include the code that is pertinent.

Comment: But you can load the mentioned JSON object file into the [official editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), right? 3D Assets have sometimes extreme scalings so the asset might be too big in order to see it correctly. Or it has an offset and thus is positioned  outside of your view frustum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the `init` and `animate` function outside the loop and called them separately. I also adjusted the camera as @Mugen87 pointed out that scale of the objects being rendered was an issue as well. The cells now render each object in their individual cells - I can currently render out 50 cells in the same viewport.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>three.js webgl - multiple elements</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    a {
        color: #08f;
    }
    #content {
        position: absolute;
        height: 600px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        top: 0; width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 3em 0 0 0;
    }
    #c {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .list-item {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 1em;
        /* box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); */
    }
    .list-item .scene {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .list-item .description {
        color: #888;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: large;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<div id="content">
    <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - multiple elements - webgl</div>
</div>

<script id="template" type="notjs">
    <div class="scene"></div>
    <div class="description">Scene $</div>
</script>

<script type="module">
    var canvas;
    var scenes = [];
    var renderer;
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    // number of cells in grid
    var gridCount = 50;

    init();
    animate();

    function loadObject(scene){
        loader.load("./test_obj.json", 

        function( objectLoaded ) {
            scene.add(objectLoaded);
        }, 
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' ,error);
        }
        );
    }

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById( "c" );

        var template = document.getElementById( "template" ).text;
        var content = document.getElementById( "content" );
        for ( var i = 0; i < gridCount; i ++ ) {
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // make a list item
            var element = document.createElement( "div" );
            element.className = "list-item";
            element.innerHTML = template.replace( '$', i + 1 );
            // Look up the element that represents the area
            // we want to render the scene
            scene.userData.element = element.querySelector( ".scene" );
            content.appendChild( element );
            // instance cameara
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, (window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight), 0.5, 2000 );
            // adjust camera
            camera.position.set(-109,422,-593);
            scene.userData.camera = camera;
            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( scene.userData.camera, scene.userData.element );
            scene.userData.controls = controls;
            loadObject(scene);
            scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xaaaaaa, 0x444444 ) );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            scenes.push( scene );
        }
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvas, antialias: true } );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    }
    function updateSize() {
        var width = canvas.clientWidth;
        var height = canvas.clientHeight;
        if ( canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height ) {
            renderer.setSize( width, height, false );
        }
    }
    function animate() {
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    }
    function render() {
        updateSize();
        canvas.style.transform = `translateY(${window.scrollY}px)`;
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
        renderer.setScissorTest( false );
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xe0e0e0 );
        renderer.setScissorTest( true );
        scenes.forEach( function ( scene ) {
            // so something moves
            scene.children[ 0 ].rotation.y = Date.now() * 0.001;
            // get the element that is a place holder for where we want to
            // draw the scene
            var element = scene.userData.element;
            // get its position relative to the page's viewport
            var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

            // set the perse
            var width = rect.right - rect.left;
            var height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
            var left = rect.left;
            var bottom = renderer.domElement.clientHeight - rect.bottom;
            renderer.setViewport( left, bottom, width, height );
            renderer.setScissor( left, bottom, width, height );
            var camera = scene.userData.camera;

            scene.userData.controls.update();
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        } );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```